# 4 partitions, which to delete?

Tags: 12.04

I have these partitions, and I need to delete one to install Ubuntu

I have

Dev SDA 1, NTFS, windows 7 (loader)
Dev SDA 2, NTFS, windows 7 recovery environment (loader) My main windows partition
SDA 3
15090 MB
Same name as SDA 2
SDA 4 Says nothing.

Yes, I want to dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try    `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` , then "p" and enter this will show you all table then "d" for delete,
select range (1 to 4)
Or you can install `gparted` by 
 `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Comment: Add lsblk to your answer, too, for listing partitions

Answer (score 0):

If you are planing to install Ubuntu along with windows7 then login windows 7 and from disk management create 15 to 20GB of space that was not partitioned in windows(by shrinking the already available partition). Insert Ubuntu installation disk by selecting cd drive as primary boot device. While installing  it will ask you to select the partitions listing as you mentioned above. From there select the partition mostly SDA 4 and try installing OS by default mode. Where the installer itself will create swap and other required bootable partitions.

Please check the below URL for details instruction.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86KHkeBpsbA&noredirect=1

Comment: Sda4 is HP Tools, is it safe to delete?

Comment: NO don't delete it. Shrink any storage disk like D drive  and create some unallocated space in disk from disk management. Then try installing ubuntu selecting that unallocated space.

Comment: It just says unusable the free space.

Comment: Help? Its unusable?

Comment: This is the common issue in HP laptops.


I have copied work around for your case from our forum itself. try the below.

Comment: What do I do then?